# main function does not return anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, program-entry-point

I have a python script which consists of two functions
tolist_converter and main

```
def tolist_converter(i_mass,i_vol,t_mass,t_vol,t_cost,p_id):
    # Item masses, volumes
    item_mass = i_mass.tolist()
    item_vol = i_vol.tolist()
    
    # Mass & volume capacities of trucks
    truck_mass = t_mass.tolist()
    truck_vol = t_vol.tolist()
    
    # Cost of using each truck
    truck_cost = t_cost.tolist()
    id_series = p_id
    
    return(item_mass,item_vol,truck_mass,truck_vol,truck_cost, id_series)
```

main function

```
def main(item_m,item_v,truck_m,truck_v,truck_c, id_s):
    item_mass,item_vol,truck_mass,truck_vol,truck_cost, id_series = tolist_converter(item_m,item_v,truck_m,truck_v,truck_c, id_s)
    return item_mass
```

and i am calling the main function like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("this function is running")
    main(data["Weight"],data["Volume"],truck["Weight"],truck["Volume"],truck["Price"],data["Pid"])
```

when I run this main function in terminal it does not give me anything. According to my understanding when the main function is called it should return **item_mass** in the terminal screen.

this is the output of terminal

> C:\Users\Sid\Downloads\aggregator-master\django_school\classroom\views>py Disp.py
>
> this function is running

Comment: Looks like `main()` *is* returning something, but you're doing nothing with it. Perhaps you intended to `print()` the output?

Comment: save whatever `main` is returning to a variable  `var= main(data["Weight"], data["Volume"], truck["Weight"],truck["Volume"],truck["Price"],data["Pid"])`  and check whiter its returning any value using `print(var)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `print`ing the `main` function :

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    print("this function is running")
    print(main(data["Weight"],data["Volume"],truck["Weight"],truck["Volume"],truck["Price"],data["Pid"]))
```